# Python PIL Editing Pixels versus ImageDraw.point

Tags: python, image

I am working on an image-generation program, and I have an issue trying to directly edit the pixels of an image.

My original method, which works, was simply:

```
image = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), background)
drawing_image = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# in some loop that determines what to draw and at what color
    drawing_image.point((x, y), color)
```

This works fine, but I thought directly editing pixels might be slightly faster. I plan on using "very" high resolutions (maybe 10000px by 10000px), so even a slight decrease in time per pixel will be a large decrease overall.

I tried using this:

```
image = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), background)
pixels = image.load()

# in some loop that determines what to draw and at what color
    pixels[x][y] = color # note: color is a hex-formatted string, i.e "#00FF00"
```

This gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_path\my_file.py", line 100, in <module>
    main()
  File "my_path\my_file.py", line 83, in main
    pixels[x][y] = color
TypeError: argument must be sequence of length 2
```

How does the actual `pixels[x][y]` work? I seem to be missing a fundamental concept here (I've never worked with directly editing pixels prior to this), or at least just not understanding what arguments are required. I even tried `pixels[x][y] = (0, 0, 0)`, but that raised the same error.

In addition, is there a faster way to edit the pixels? I've heard that using the `pixels[x][y] = some_color` is faster than drawing to the image, but I'm open to any other faster method.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass a tuple index as `pixels[(x, y)]` or simply `pixels[x, y]`, for example:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!python
from PIL import Image

width = 4
height = 4
background = (0, 0, 0, 255)

image = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), background)
pixels = image.load()

pixels[0, 0] = (255, 0, 0, 255)
pixels[0, 3] = (0, 255, 0, 255)
pixels[3, 3] = (0, 0, 255, 255)
pixels[3, 0] = (255, 255, 255, 255)

image.save("image.png")
```